# Attempted to upsert a null list Error is in expression '{! save }' in component

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension, null, saveresult

The full error I am getting:
**Attempted to upsert a null list
Error is in expression '{! save }' in component apex:commandButton in page casepage: Class.CaseController.save: line 15, column 1**

Here is my apex page code

```
 <apex:pageBlockSection title="Create a Case">
            <apex:form>
                <table>
                <tr>
                    <b><td>Type:</td></b>
                    <td><apex:inputField style="width:100px" value="{! Case.Type }"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Status:</td>
                    <td><apex:inputField value="{! Case.Status }"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Origin:</td>
                    <td><apex:inputField value="{! Case.Origin }"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Reason:</td>
                    <td><apex:inputField value="{! Case.Reason }"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Email:</td>
                    <td><apex:inputField style="width:300px" value="{! Case.SuppliedEmail }"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Phone:</td>
                    <td><apex:inputField style="width:300px" value="{! Case.SuppliedPhone }"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Subject:</td>
                    <td><apex:inputField style="width:300px" value="{! Case.Subject }"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Description:</td>
                    <td><apex:inputField style="width:550px; height:100px" value="{! Case.Description }"/></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <apex:commandButton action="{! save }" value="Save" />
            </apex:form>
            <apex:messages/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </div>
```

And here is my apex class code:

```
public class CaseController {
    public ApexPages.StandardController stdCntrlr {get; set;}
    
    public CaseController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        
        stdCntrlr = controller;
    }
    
    public Case cs{get; set;}
    public CaseController(){
        cs = new Case();
    }
    
    public PageReference save(){
        upsert cs;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume your page starts off with `<apex:page standardController="Case"`. Because of this, you're calling the single-parameter constructor, not the zero-parameter constructor--the `cs` variable is never initialized. There are two possible fixes. I'd prefer this one:

```
public PageReference save(){
    if(cs != null) {
        upsert cs;
    } else {
        stdCntrlr.save();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Or, you can go the other route, by initializing `cs` properly:

```
public CaseController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    cs = (Case)controller.getRecord();
    stdCntrlr = controller;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The first one worked.